# Filter by character, creating column with results

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I am trying to create a graph showing two data sets, if it is that character or if it is not that character.

Currently I am working with something like:

```
setosa <-  iris%>%
  filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(., pattern = "setosa")))
```

Using the iris example I would like to be able to search out a character in a string eg: `setosa`, then draw a graph showing `setosa` and `not setosa`.

See below an example of my data frame, the pd.Sails column is full off different connotations of the same character.  I want to be able to draw a graph of pd$TWA v pd.TWS and the data shows results from the pd$Sails column based on name, so `J2 N` or `not J2 N`

Sorry for moving away from Iris I was struggling to convey the problem!

My current df is:

```
 pd.Boat   pd.Sails pd.TWA pd.TWS
1  Sojana RMAIN/J2 N   40.9   13.7
2  Sojana RMAIN/J2 N   38.8   13.0
3  Sojana RMAIN/J2 N   37.8   13.3
4  Sojana RMAIN/J2 N   37.3   13.3
5  Sojana RMAIN/J2 N   45.2   13.2
6  Sojana RMAIN/J2 N   50.6   13.2
```

```
dput(head)

structure(list(pd.Boat = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Sojana", class = "factor"), 
    pd.Sails = structure(c(36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L), .Label = c("RMAIN", 
    "RMAIN/A2", "RMAIN/A2 C - north 19", "RMAIN/A2 C - north 19/Big Jonny", 
    "RMAIN/A2 C - north 19/CMiz SS", "RMAIN/A2 C - north 19/Spi SS v2/Big Jonny", 
    "RMAIN/A2 Doyle", "RMAIN/A2 Doyle/Big Jonny", "RMAIN/A2 Doyle/Spi SS v2", 
    "RMAIN/A2 Doyle/Spi SS v2/Big Jonny", "RMAIN/A2 N", "RMAIN/A2 N/Big Jonny", 
    "RMAIN/A2 N/Mizzen SS V2", "RMAIN/A2 N/Spi SS v2/Big Jonny", 
    "RMAIN/A2/Big Jonny", "RMAIN/A2/Big Jonny/Spi SS v2", "RMAIN/A2/Mizzen SS V2", 
    "RMAIN/A2/Spi SS v2", "RMAIN/A2/Spi SS v2/Big Jonny", "RMAIN/A2/Spi SS v2/Mizzen SS V2", 
    "RMAIN/A2N", "RMAIN/A2N/Big Jonny", "RMAIN/A2N/Mizzen SS V2", 
    "RMAIN/A2N/Spi SS v2/Big Jonny", "RMAIN/A4", "RMAIN/A4/Big Jonny", 
    "RMAIN/A4/Big Jonny/Mizzen SS V2", "RMAIN/A4/CMiz SS", "RMAIN/A4/J2 N/Big Jonny", 
    "RMAIN/A4/Mizzen SS V2", "RMAIN/A4/Spi SS v2/Big Jonny", 
    "RMAIN/J1 N", "RMAIN/J1 N/Black Betty v2", "RMAIN/J1 N/CMiz SS", 
    "RMAIN/J1 N/Mizzen SS V2", "RMAIN/J2 N", "RMAIN/J2 N/Black Betty v2", 
    "RMAIN/J2 N/CMiz SS", "RMAIN/J2 N/Mizzen SS V2"), class = "factor"), 
    pd.TWA = c(40.9, 38.8, 37.8, 37.3, 45.2, 50.6), pd.TWS = c(13.7, 
    13, 13.3, 13.3, 13.2, 13.2)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: what is you expected output?

Comment: My guess is that expected result would be a new column, that would have "setosa" and "notsetosa" columns.

Comment: I take it you don't know which variable will hold the data you are looking for? Will it be in more than one variable?

Comment: @James yes that is the problem the character is complex and I only want to filter by certain elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` to do this.

```
iris$sns <- ifelse(iris$Species == "setosa", "setosa", "notsetosa")

set.seed(357)
iris <- iris[sample(1:nrow(iris)),]

> head(iris[sample(1:nrow(iris)),])
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species       sns
17          5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4     setosa    setosa
9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2     setosa    setosa
42          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3     setosa    setosa
34          5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2     setosa    setosa
96          5.7         3.0          4.2         1.2 versicolor notsetosa
68          5.8         2.7          4.1         1.0 versicolor notsetosa
```

Comment: Thank you @Roman, what if my character name is something like 'set/tos/a' and I want to do the same with 'tos' or 'not tos'. ? So search for specific elements of a character.

Comment: `ifelse(iris$Species == "tos", "tos", "not tos")`. See `?ifelse` for more info.